# How do I make a Looping Function in flutter

Tags: function, loops, flutter

I want to make a widget(a fan) spin around untill the user clicks it.
And for that, I thought I was gonna use a function, but then the question is;

> How do I make a looping function, that stoppes when a bool = false?

This is my current function (that doesn't loop):

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    angleController = AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 230));
    angleController .addListener(() {
      setState(() {
        fanAngle = angleController.value * 90 / 360 * pi * 2;
      });
    });
  }
```

And the GestureDetector function:

```
void fanRotation() {
      if(angleController.status == AnimationStatus.completed){
        angleController.stop();
        fanState = false;
      } else if (angleController.status == AnimationStatus.dismissed) {
      angleController.forward();
      fanState = true;
    
    }
  }
}
```

I want it to have a continuous loop, so no stopping and starting again.

Answer (score 1):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can directly call `angleController.repeat()` in `initState()` and call `angleController.stop()` when click `fan`
code snippet

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    angleController =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(seconds: 3));

    angleController.repeat();
  }
  ...
  GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        angleController.stop();
      },
      child: Icon(
        Icons.forward,
        color: Colors.pink,
        size: 100.0,
      )),
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController angleController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    angleController =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(seconds: 3));

    angleController.repeat();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            AnimatedBuilder(
              animation: angleController,
              builder: (_, child) {
                return Transform.rotate(
                  angle: angleController.value * pi * 2,
                  child: child,
                );
              },
              child: GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    angleController.stop();
                  },
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.forward,
                    color: Colors.pink,
                    size: 100.0,
                  )),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a `timer.periodic`:
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Timer/Timer.periodic.html

Use it to keep the rotation function running and just turn it off when clicked.

```
var timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 5), (timer) {
  //Your function goes here
});
  
// Cancel the timer
timer.cancel();
```